# Windows 10 File Explorer, Is there a way to amend thumbnail size?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

In Windows 10 File Explorer/Standard Open file dialog > View > Large Icons.

Is there a way to amend this thumbnail size? Large icons are too small & Extra large are too large.

A registry setting to amend it's pixel size, maybe?

Comment: Unless you think you can reverse engineer Windows, the two choices (of several) are Large and Extra Large. You will need to adapt to the one that suits you best.

Comment: `<Ctrl>+<ScrollWheel>` gives continuous adjustment of icon size. That will be saved with other aspects of the view.